# Первичный ключ обязательно должен быть уникальным?

Tags: sql, база-данных

Первичный ключ обязательно должен быть уникальным?

Answer (score 3):

Да, обязательно. В [Википедии](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_key) об этом однозначно говорится:

> In the relational model of databases, а primary key is a *specific choice* of a *minimal* set of attributes (columns) that **uniquely** specify a tuple (row) in a relation (table).

---

Техническая реализация на стороне СУБД выглядит так:
При указании в свойстве колонки `PRIMARY KEY` будет неявно создан индекс с типом `UNIQUE` и попытка записи с уже существующим значением закончится ошибкой.